# I am trying to access google signed In user's calendar events data on the flutter app, I am using firebase for authentication of the user

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have been stuck on this for the past few days. Can anybody help me? please?

I have tried to implement this in multiple ways possible, but couldn't do it. I am on a time crunch anybody please help me?